# Problem with this for loop || ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. ||

Tags: python, for-loop

I am geting this error message when I execute the following code in Pyhton.

> "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

I can't get it to read the tasks.txt file and I can't seem to fix it.

```
elif menu == 'va': 
            task_list = open("tasks.txt", "r+") #opens task file
            for line in task_list:        
                assignee, title, description, due_date, date, completed = line.split(", ")
                print(f'''
                Name: {assignee}
                Title: {title}
                Description: {description}
                Due Date: {due_date}
                Date Assigned: {date}
                Task Complete: {completed}''')
                task_list.close()
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

I tried to indent the task-list.close() file so that it is outside of the for loop as looking on here I think that might be causing it to close before it can print. I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you have `task_list.close()` within the `for` loop? Perhaps you indented it too much. You should unindent this to be under the `for`. Better still, learn about `with` and `open` so that you don't make this mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

`task_list.close()` closes the file, meaning that subsequent calls to `task_list` will fail with the IO error you are seeing.

You should de-dent this to move it outside the loop, so that it will only close the file once the loop has finished executing

```
elif menu == 'va': 
            task_list = open("tasks.txt", "r+") #opens task file

            #start loop through file
            for line in task_list:        
                assignee, title, description, due_date, date, completed = line.split(", ")
                print(f'''
                Name: {assignee}
                Title: {title}
                Description: {description}
                Due Date: {due_date}
                Date Assigned: {date}
                Task Complete: {completed}''')

            #loop has finished - close file
            task_list.close()
```

Alternatively, you can let `Python` do all of the work for managing the file state for you! By using a `with` block, we tell the interpreter that we need the file open whilst we are in the block - and when it reaches the end of the block, the file is closed automatically.

Updated code:

```
elif menu == 'va': 
            with open("tasks.txt", "r+") as task_list: #open file

                #begin loop
                for line in task_list:        
                    assignee, title, description, due_date, date, completed = line.split(", ")
                    print(f'''
                    Name: {assignee}
                    Title: {title}
                    Description: {description}
                    Due Date: {due_date}
                    Date Assigned: {date}
                    Task Complete: {completed}''')

            #with has finished, so file is automatically closed
```

Comment: Maybe an example opening the file using a context manager could be great help too, with open... :)

Comment: Yes, keep this example of where to place the `.close()` and then add another snippet where you use `with open(...`.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion guys :)